# Django Action Stream error No Module named 'actstreamdjango'

Tags: django

I am building a Django app, and wrote in the code as it exists on the documentation to use Action Streams.

This means:
'actstream' is in my INSTALLED_APPS

I copied ('^activity/', include('actstream.urls')) into my urlpatterns

and I copied the text in the Settings documentation to settings.py

and I get the error: No Module named 'actstreamdjango'

There is nothing else in the Get Started guide... what am I missing?

Comment: It should be `'actstream',` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. You are missing the comma.

Comment: Yup, that was my mistake. Derp